# How to use MaterializeCss with Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, materialize

I don't want to use [Vue-Material](https://github.com/vuematerial/vue-material) nor [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/).

I want to use [Materialize](https://materializecss.com/).
What I do is:

```
npm install materialize-css@next
```

In main.js, where my new Vue App is defined I import Materialize like this:

```
import 'materialize-css'
```

Somehow the javascript is working, but the CSS is not loading; I test it with a [Card Reveal](https://materializecss.com/cards.html#reveal).

The swapping animation works, but it is not styled. Card Reveal is one of the reasons why I want to use MaterializeCss, those other two don't provide this functionality. And I also want to use 'normal' HTML elements instead of using 100 of new elements (for example in vuetify).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This line imports the javascript (the entry point of the npm module from node_modules folder):

```
import 'materialize-css'
```

To import the CSS files just do this:

```
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css'
```

Comment: I found I needed to add `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">` in the `index.html` in order for the icons to load. eg. hamburger icon for mobile nav.

Answer (score 22):

### Step 1: installation

```
npm install materialize-css@next --save
npm install material-design-icons --save
```

### Step 2: import materialize css in src/main.js

At `src/main.js`

```
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css'
import 'material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css'
```

### Step 3: initialize materialize components

Add following code in your component(say App.vue):

```
import M from 'materialize-css'

export default {
...
mounted () {
    M.AutoInit()
},
...
```

Answer (score 2):

I would also recommend you add the materialize css CDN in the `index.html`. Aand also create a script tag and add this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    M.AutoInit();
 });
```

Comment: Not sure how vue and materializecss share the DOM. I recommend running function once the component is mounted: `mounted: function() { M.AutoInit() }`

Answer (score 0):

The answer from bruinspaw helped me a lot, I would like to suggest a couple of updates since this thread is over five years old:

### 1. Installation

```
pnpm install materialize-css@next
pnpm install material-design-icons --save
```

(no changes, except I prefer [pnpm](https://pnpm.io/) over npm - npm is also fine)
(see below if you want to use material-design-icons-iconfont instead)

### 2. import *Material Design icons* and Materialize CSS

In src/main.ts (or main.js if you don't use typescript):

```
import 'material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css'
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css'
import 'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js'
```

Note the first import, which is an addition (and see below if you use material-design-icons-iconfont)

### 3. Initialize components

In App.vue (or the relevant component):

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { onMounted } from 'vue'
import M from 'materialize-css'
// ... other code
onMounted(() => {
  M.AutoInit()
})
</script>
```

(replace "ts" with "js" if you don't use typescript).
The main difference from the original post is that I use the (Vue 3) Composition API (as evident by 'setup') insted of the (older) Options API.

The main difference is that you don't have to include the `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">` in index.html as you would with the solution in the first post (and as pointed out by David North). As a last point, I have begun using [material-design-icons-iconfont](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-design-icons-iconfont) instead of material-design-icons, as I find this to be a more streamlined version of the Material Design Icons. Do the following changes if you would like to try that:

1. Install with `pnpm install material-design-icons-iconfont --save` instead of `pnpm install material-design-icons --save`
2. `import 'material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css'` instead of `import 'material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css'`

(this is my first post on stack overflow, so I hope I'm not doing anything wrong updating an old thread like this)