# Using materializecss in vuejs. How i can pass options to the javascript components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, materialize

Like this options object

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.materialboxed');
    var instances = M.Materialbox.init(elems, {options});
  });
```

but in a vuejs component

Comment: does [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52969652/how-to-use-materializecss-with-vue-js) help? - there's also this [materializecss-vuejs-component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/materializecss-vuejs-component)

Comment: nope, i was looking for a way to do it without using external modules